# There exists $f$ such that $f(x+c)-f(x)-f(y+c)+f(y)> g(x+c,y+c)-g(x,y)$?

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

For each continuous function $g$ defined on $[0,1]^2$, does there exist a real function $f$ such that

$f(x+c)-f(x)-f(y+c)+f(y)> g(x+c,y+c)-g(x,y)$ , for all $x,y,c>0$?

(for simplicity, assume RHS$>0$, $x>y$, $g(x,y)>0$ when $x>y$, and $g(x,x)=0$).

---

My try:  assuming $f,g$ are differentiable, let $c=\epsilon$, the question reduces to:

$f'(x)-f'(y)>(1,1)\cdot\partial g(x,y)$ which is considerably simpler. I cannot solve the non-differentiable case.

Comment: Assume $x = y$, then left part is $0$, while right part is pretty much arbitrary.

Comment: @mihaild $x>y$ though

Comment: I don't see this i problem statement. Anyway, this means that at least continuous $f$ will not work.

Comment: @mihaild I kind of agree with you!